# Ruby CSV not reading comma-formatted numbers in quoted strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm using ruby's CSV class (ruby 2.1.5) in a Rails app to load records from an uploaded csv file. Users are creating the csv files from Excel with a "Save As", and depending on the format of the numbers, they might be saved as quoted strings with commas -- in which case the part of the number after the comma is dropped.

If the input value is `"3,500"`, then `3500` should be saved, but instead it is `3`.

I realize it is possible to clean this up in Excel, but it also seems like something that should be easily handled (and I would get a major WTF from the users if I have to tell them the program can't handle this basic case.) Also, since the headers of the csv file match the column names in the database, I haven't had to write column-specific handlers - I just do an attributes assignment. I'm hoping to keep it that way because I have quite a few more affected columns than what I'm including in my example.

Input record:

```
recordid,valcurrent,valdate
11015,"3,500",6/7/2013
```

Processing function

```
def import_csv(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, skip_blanks: true, converters: :all) do |row|
    # hash the input row 
    row_hash = row.to_hash
    # create a new row with the hash in original_record
    fl = self.forecast_lines.create(original_record: row_hash.to_s)
    # write the hash to the record attributes
    fl.attributes = row_hash
    fl.save
  end
end
```

Original record hash:

```
Original record: {:recordid=>"11015", :valcurrent=>"3,500", :valdate=>"6/7/2013"}
```

The data type for valcurrent is float. But the valcurrent value that gets saved to the database is not `3500.0`, but `3.0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a custom converter that handles your number columns correctly. Not sure if this covers all of your possible formatting options, but it'd look something like this:

Create a lambda:

```
comma_numbers = ->(s) {(s =~ /^\d+,/) ? (s.gsub(',','').to_f) : s}
```

Add it to your converters:

```
CSV::Converters[:comma_numbers] = comma_numbers
```

The new converter is not included in converters: :all so add it as an array:

```
converters: [:all, :comma_numbers]
```

Comment: Thanks - this works great, and now that you've got me pointed the right direction I will be able to use this to handle other cases.

Comment: I added an edit to your answer based on what I did to make it work, but please correct if there's a better way.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer above to explicitly call out that you have to add your new converter to your list of converters.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with CSV but how Ruby converts string to float.

In Ruby:

```
"3,500".to_f => 3.0
```

That's the reason 3.0 is getting stored in database. You should change your import_csv method to handle commas.

Also I don't think you should be doing row_hash.to_s in create. Create method as such accepts a hash as a parameter.

Comment: I get your first point about string to float conversion, but I thought using converters: :all would cause CSV to convert the number for me. On your second point, I actually want to save the entire hash as a string in a field called original_record for debug purposes - didn't explain that in my OP.