# Ruby (no Rails) How to write numeric values using a decimal comma to csv file

Tags: mysql, ruby, csv, decimal

I'm trying to read data from a MySql query I wrote and write it to a csv file.
All of this using ruby itself, no Ruby on Rails or any WebFramework involved.

Unfortunately, the numbers are required to have a decimal comma instead of a decimal point and the column separator of the csv file has to be ";".

This is what I have written so far, but this only produces decimal points on the numeric columns (CSV-;-separator works):

```
require 'mysql'
require 'csv'

begin
  con = Mysql.new conn['server'], conn['user'], conn['pw'] , conn['db']
  rs = con.query(sql)

  CSV.open(output_file,"wb",{:col_sep => ";"}) do |csv|

    rs.each do |row|
      csv << row
    end

  end

rescue Mysql::Error => e
  puts e.errno
  puts e.error
ensure
  con.close if con
end
```

Is there any non-Rails-way to do this?
Everything I found was some kind of ActiveRecord class method which is not really applicable to this example (at least I don't know how to do it, maybe you can point me in the right direction).

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Stefan

Comment: Convert the number to a string and replace `.` with `,`, i.e. `num.to_s.tr('.', ',')`

Comment: In theorey you could write a converter (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306695/ruby-csv-not-reading-comma-formatted-numbers-in-quoted-strings) where you do transform `to_s` and then `gsub` (or `tr`) on it. When I needed converters a couple of years ago I found very few useful information about then, though.

Comment: Can you change the "locale" to be, say, German?  That way, `,` will be the "decimal point".

Comment: @RickJames my locale is already set to German (as I am living there), I just double-checked that... 
For the moment, I'm going with a string-replacement of "." -> ",", but I hoped that there would be a solution a little bit more "pretty" than that.